# clearing canvas in html not refreshing without scroll in electron

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, electron

my problem is simple, I've made a drawing board in html canvas. everything works ok, except when I want to cleat the whole canvas.

I'm using this function `context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);` and it's working fine, except that most of the time the canvas is not cleared until after I do a small scroll or any action on the browser (I even tried to make a hack to scroll programmatically after the scroll and it didn't work)

It seems to me like the canvas only refreshes after a certain event on the browser, but i don't know how to force this refresh.

Any idea of what is happening and how to solve it ?

My code below :

```
<span><input type="image" src="img/clear1.png" name="clear1" width="50" height="50" onclick="clear1()"></span>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv1');
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
    canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
    if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
        canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
    }
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
});    

function clear1(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
}
```

I found that this issue only happens in electron

Comment: How are you calling the function? Can you show us an example snippet that reproduces the bug?

Comment: I edited the question to add the parts of the code

Comment: Are you getting a "clearRect is not a function" error? From this snippet, I can't tell if you've actually defined  your `context` variable outside of the on ready function. Can `clear1` correctly access `context`?

Comment: no no it is globally defined, I am sure it is working, because it clears the canvas, it's just that sometimes i have to scroll the browser a little for the clear to actually happen, it's like it is clearing the canvas but the view is not refreshed.

Comment: Im having the exact same issue.  When I press a button, it modifies the some settings, clears the canvas and redraws.  Except it's only clearing every OTHER draw call.  And I cannot figure out why.  It doesn't appear to be an issue with canvas, maybe with electron.

Answer (score 0):

The context variable are only defined in $(document).ready() scope, try it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv1');
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
    canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
    if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
        canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
    }
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    window.clear1 = function(){
        context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    }
});
```

Or:

```
// global declaration
var context = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
//keep your logic here 

}); 
 function clear1(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
 }
```

Comment: Yes indeed it is declared as a global variable. The error I have is not a syntax error, because eventually the canvas is being cleared. It is just done after a scroll,resize...any change in the browser or after several clicks on the clear button

Comment: OK, I'll see if I can replicate the error, but it would be interesting you include details of your code, such as the library you are using to manipulate the canvas.